# ¿Cómo hacer peticiones en segundo plano con retrofit2 para usar NotificationChannel en tiempo real?

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit, android-notifications, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Tengo definida mi "ApiService" y mi "RetrofitClient" para realizar la petición al servidor, tengo implementado el servicio del objeto, pero a la hora de realizar la invocación desde un "ViewModel" de un "Fragment" no se como mantener mantener la petición de forma indefinida para poder mostrar una notificación al usuario cuando haya algún mensaje nuevo para leer.

Esta sería la petición "GET":

```
@GET("messageReceived/{receiver}")
Call<List<Message>> getReceivedMessagesCall(@Path("receiver") String receiver);
```

Aquí el método de "Retrofit":

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
    if (retrofitInstance == null) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).create();

        retrofitInstance =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(REMOTE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }

    return retrofitInstance;
}
```

La petición del servicio:

```
public List<Message> getSentMessages(String sender) throws ApiException {
    Response<List<Message>> messagesResponse;

    try {
        messagesResponse = apiService.getSentMessagesCall(sender).execute();

        if (messagesResponse.isSuccessful()) {
            return messagesResponse.body();
        }

        throw TypeErrorConvert.parseError(messagesResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ApiException apiException = new ApiException(TypeError.SENT_MESSAGES, e.getMessage());

        Log.e(TAG, apiException.getMessage(), e);

        throw apiException;
    }
}
```

Aquí guardo los datos en local con "Room":

```
public List<Message> getMessagesReceived(String receiver) throws ApiException {
    List<Message> messagesReceived = messageService.getReceivedMessages(receiver);

    for (Message message : messagesReceived) {
        insert(message);
    }

    return messagesReceived;
}
```

Esto sería la función del "ViewModel":

```
public MutableLiveData<List<Message>> getMessages(LegalGuardian legalGuardian) {
    MutableLiveData<List<Message>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    new Thread(
        () -> {
            try {
                List<Message> messages = messageRepository.getMessagesReceived(legalGuardian.getPerson());

                mutableLiveData.postValue(messages);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                setType(e.getType());
                mutableLiveData.postValue(null);
            }
        }).start();

    return mutableLiveData;
}
```

Y por último la invocación desde el "Fragment" en cuestión:

```
messagesViewModel
    .getMessages(legalGuardian, isSent)
    .observe(
        getViewLifecycleOwner(),
        messages ->
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(messages)));
```

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta para realizar esta petición? ¿Debería mantenerlo en el "Fragment" o debería mover la lógica al "Ativity" principal? ¿Cómo podría integrar todo este proceso con "NotificationChannel"?

Aclaración:

He tratado de buscar documentación, guías y ejemplos pero no he encontrado nada que me ayude a entender como usar "Retrofit" en segundo plano con "NotificationChannel".

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

RxAndroid será muy útil en este caso. Puedes crear un bucle como este

```
Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(1000, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
        public void call(Long aLong) {
            // here is the task that should repeat
        }
    });
```

Si quieres detener el bucle solo llama

```
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Entiendo que esto debería usarlo desde el propio "Fragment", ¿verdad? El problema sería que si la "APP" se ha cerrado o no se ha cargado el "Fragment" no tengo claro hasta que punto puede ser lo que necesito.